# The Limit of asking a question

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rate-limiting, time-limit

I have a question for MSE.

I noticed that the number of asking question is limtted. I guess, someone ask 60 questions per a month.

My limit finished. And I know that as time goes on, I ask few questions; for example, I asked only one question everyday. This too little for me. I need to ask more question until august,1.

Does there exist a solution? For example, like that the more question I answer, the more questions I ask.. and the like.

What should I do so as to ask more questions and to remove the asking question limit?

Please give me a suggestion and information.

Thank you.

Best regards..

Comment: The limit is 50 questions per 30 days. It is a rolling limit however, meaning that if say you asked 2 questions 30 days ago then tomorrow you would be able to ask 2 more questions.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote false the number of limit. I know this is rolling. I tried to say this above. But now I asked no question for two-three days. But I need to ask until end of July. I guess, isn't there any suggestion to handle the problem only for next one week?:( @AlexBecker thank you..

Comment: No, there is no way to get around the limit (and attempting to do so will result in a suspension). You should try to put more thought into your questions and ask fewer of them.

Comment: I want to attempt, but I dont have any info to do such a thing. Thus, No problem. This is just a joke:) by the way, ı have a question. I guess, signing up a new account doesnt create a problem in terms of the website's rule. Is it? @AlexBecker

Comment: Creating a new account in order to post more questions than the limit allows is strictly against the rules. The new account will be deleted.

Comment: Knowing this info is good for me. Thank you for helping. I will search other websites to ask math question. There is No another choice. Best, Dear @AlexBecker

Comment: "I need to ask more question until august,1." Why?

Comment: Because I am studying by myself. I prepared an exam, say "exit test" ( I dont know exact name of the exam in English.) Anyway, I am preparing the exam by myself, there is nobody I can ask. So, I am using the website. Why you ask such a question? @Did

Comment: Because of the time limit you mentioned.

Comment: Okay,well, does my answer satisfy you? @Did

Comment: By the way, my question gets more upvote, I guess, this is many people's problem. Can moderators increase the number of asking question per a month? @Did I think, this is a good solution :)

Comment: @Alex: is this particular rule enforced by software, or by mods? If it's the latter, can a user request an exception? There doesn't seem to be any risk in allowing such a backup account to exist.

Comment: "does my answer satisfy you?" Fully, in the sense that you explained your motivations. And/But I am opposed to the "solution" you are proposing/asking, mainly for the reasons explained by Asaf in a comment below.

Comment: Sometimes people have asked mathematical questions [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36).

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 AFAIK the moderators cannot lift the limit for a particular users, see the comments mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/removal-of-upper-limit-of-questions-you-can-ask?lq=1#comment18799_4806)

Comment: @Martin, I see that, but was wondering something more along the lines of [Arturo's inquiry](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi#comment18571_4742)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Well, Willie's comment is addressing that. Anyway, to be sure, I've asked on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190863/are-moderators-able-to-remove-the-monthly-question-quota-for-a-particular-user).

Comment: Its August 1st.

Comment: So? @JoeHobbit I took the exam.

Comment: What exam are you referring to?

Comment: Introduction to analysis @JoeHobbit

Comment: I'd appreciate hearing your thoughts and opinions on my very related question at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/more-helpful-non-uniform-upper-limit-of-questions. I of course would appreciate your support for it.

Answer (score 21):

I upvoted here because I think the question is certainly a valid one to ask, but not because I agree with the solution.

Allowing a single user to ask an unlimited number of questions in a given period of time opens an easy door for spam--with the current question limits, a spambot with an account here can post a maximum of $50$ spam posts in a $30$ day period.  So, this measure protects against spam.

Also, an increase in the allowed rate of asking questions isn't really needed for self-studiers.  If you set your own schedule, why does it matter if you take a few days longer?  It only really matters for people who are asking questions due to an outside class.

Finally, this has been discussed before, not only [on](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/removal-of-upper-limit-of-questions-you-can-ask?lq=1) [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/do-we-limit-how-often-someone-may-ask-about-their-homework?lq=1) [site's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9218/why-i-cannot-ask-further-questions?lq=1) [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/i-need-to-ask-more-questions-and-have-asked-6?rq=1), but [also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125926/how-to-increase-quota-for-questions?lq=1) [Meta.StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93413/how-can-we-increase-the-number-of-allowed-question-we-ask-in-stackoverflow?lq=1) (the main meta). (each word is a different link, btw)

In short, it's not going to happen.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the explanation. I understand better the reasons why the rate of asking a question is Limited. Also I am reading the previous discussions. Best, Dear @anorton

Comment: This is **not** a countermeasure for spam. It's a way to help users help themselves. If someone asks six questions a day, or 50 question in 30 days, then they are clearly not trying hard enough on their own. Moreover, with so much traffic, someone asking too much is being unfair in their share of "front page space" to other users. This are the two purposes of the question limits, in my view.

Comment: I would think that someone who wanted to spam would just create a new account.

Comment: @ZachL. Spamming on you-tube is much easier than spamming here... hence no spammers here!

Comment: @AsafKaragila [It's a way to help users help themselves. If someone asks six questions a day, or 50 question in 30 days, then they are clearly not trying hard enough on their own.]
What if he would say "Leave me alone" or "Why don't you mind your own business rather than giving an unwanted help?".
Moreover, what if his intention is to provide good questions?
You know good questions are *valuable* assets in this site.

Comment: @Makoto: If a user replies that way, then they are rude and asocial. And after all this is a community, and people are expected to be considerate of other people. Moreover if someone can produce six questions a day for 9 days a month which are **good**, then they are either using the site wrong (i.e. they can also solve most of these questions on their own, and use the site as a blog) or they are the most unique individual. Good questions are not just mathematical questions, but also how they are formulated on the site. [...]

Comment: Good questions in most of the time shouldn't even be posted. Writing a good question, there's a 75% chance that you will understand the problem so much better that you will find a solution for it on your own before even pressing "submit".

Comment: @AsafKaragila [If a user replies that way, then they are rude and asocial.]

What if he says "I'd rather what is good to me to be decided by myself than by others.
So would you please leave me alone?"?

Comment: @Makoto: Stealing from the bank is also very very good for you. You can get very rich like that. But communities work when people agree, to some extent, what is the greater good and what limitations that help to ensure that an individual have their freedom, while not damaging the rest of the community. With banks it means that you can't just take out money from the bank safe without depositing first; and with this community it means limiting the rate of your questions. If someone disagrees to that then they are antisocial and should be banned.

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Stealing from the bank is also very very good for you.] What does this have to do with posting a question in this site?

Comment: @Makoto: It's a metaphor. I made an analogy between the community in this site, and the community we have in real life. Both communities have rules, which when considered locally might not for the best interest of a particular individual. If an individual insists that only they know what is good for them, and they must be allowed to do whatever they want, for me, it is the same as if that individual decides what laws they should obey, because only they can decide what is good for them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila [*If an individual insists that only they know what is good for them, and they must be allowed to do whatever they want, for me, it is the same as if that individual decides what laws they should obey, because only they can decide what is good for them.*]
You misunderstand me.
I'm talking about this comment of yours.
[*It's a way to help users help themselves. If someone asks six questions a day, or 50 question in 30 days, then they are clearly not trying hard enough on their own.*]
You are trying to help him.
However, he is saying that "No. Thanks".

Comment: @Makoto: I don't understand what you are trying to get in this conversation. Are you trying to get me to admit "Oh, it's really a bad idea after all", or are you trying to understand my point of view? If it's the former, I'm sorry but it's not going to happen. As the site grows in size I become more and more certain that such limitation is imperative. If you are trying to understand my point of view, I'm sensing that you're not really trying hard enough to understand me. This will be my last comment on this topic to you.