# Is there a limit on number of questions a user can ask in a given time frame?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Is there a limit on number of questions a user can ask in a given time frame?

Here is  a similar question which was posted 5 years ago? It says the limit is 50 questions per 30 days. Has the limit been changed or is it the same?

[The Limit of asking a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10436/the-limit-of-asking-a-question)

Comment: Same, as far as I know. Why do you ask?

Comment: I did not want my account to get suspended just because I did not know the rule about limit. Wanted to stay safe. I am learning mathematics on my own so I had to plan which question I ask and which I should try to do on my own by spending more time and effort. :)

Comment: Indeed, and the limit is asking at most six questions in any SE day.

Comment: @amWhy Does it cover all the websites on stackexchange network.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician  you won't get suspended if you try to ask a question which exceeds the daily max, or monthly quota.  You will just be told you are unable to do so.

Comment: I believe the question limits are per site, so six questions max in one day, per site, and 50 questions max per 30 days, per site.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to the per site limits noted in Comments by @amWhy, there is a [cross-site posting limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306651/you-can-only-post-once-every-40-minutes-on-my-first-post) for "new users" (< 125 rep.) of one post per 40 minutes (applicable across all sites where the 125 reputation is not yet earned).  This restriction is based on the IP address, to prevent simple evasion of the posting limit by creating new user accounts.